# How do I modify a text field with awk?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed, awk

I want to delete text after the first colon `:` (inclusive), or replace it with nothing.

For example, `1:5:30` should be changed into `1`. I prefer an awk script to perform this job. But I do not know how to do that. Could you please give me any directions? Thanks in advance.

My data are tab-delimited, and the file looks like there are points in some cells.

```
1       313     .       T       C       30.11        1:5:30  .       .       .
1       316     .       A       T       30.80        1:5:30  .       0:8:28  .
1       317     .       T       A       31.40        1:5:36  .       0:8:28  .
```

I tried the following, but I failed with all of them:

```
sed 's/:*:*//g' mydatafile
sed 's/:[0-9]:[0-9]//g' mydatafile
```

Comment: It appears there are many answers that are correct. Go ahead and accept one of them. Click on the "tick" mark to accept an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit unclear what the desired output should be, but this is my interpretation, using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/:.*//' input
1   313 .   T   C   30.11   1
1   316 .   A   T   30.80   1
1   317 .   T   A   31.40   1
```

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F":" '{print $1}' input
1   313 .   T   C   30.11   1
1   316 .   A   T   30.80   1
1   317 .   T   A   31.40   1
```

Using Cut:

```
cut -d":" -f1 input
```

Using bash:

```
IFS=':'

while read a b; do
    echo $a
done < input
```

Alternative interpretation using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {sub(/:.*/,"",$7); print}' input
1   313 .   T   C   30.11   1   .   .   .
1   316 .   A   T   30.80   1   .   0:8:28  .
1   317 .   T   A   31.40   1   .   0:8:28  .
```

**3rd and hopefully last update**

3rd interpretation using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++){sub(/:.*/,"",$i)}; print}' input
1   313 .   T   C   30.11   1   .   .   .
1   316 .   A   T   30.80   1   .   0   .
1   317 .   T   A   31.40   1   .   0   .
```

Comment: Dear Fredrik, very nice sed/bash/awk scripts. Thanks a lot. In fact, I want all the cells with such patter (integers_1:integers_2:integers_2) be replaced by integer_1.

Comment: @jianfeng.mao it would be good if you could update your question with a listing of the correct output. I made 2 interpretations and both were wrong ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -p -e 's/:\d+:\d+//g' mydatafile
```

Comment: Dear FMc, Thanks a lot. I can not understand perl. But, I learned it is powerful from your script.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\):[0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*/\1/g' infile
```

or

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\):[0-9]\{1,\}:[0-9]\{1,\}/\1/g' infile
```

**Output**:

```
1       313     .       T       C       30.11        1  .       .       .
1       316     .       A       T       30.80        1  .       0  .
1       317     .       T       A       31.40        1  .       0  .
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the shortest one using `sed`:

```
sed -i.orig 's/\([0-9]\)*:[^ ]*/\1/g' inputfile
```

This keep a copy of the orig file as `inputfile.orig`. And replaces the file in-place.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
$ sed -e 's/:.*//' mydatafile
1       313     .       T       C       30.11        1
1       316     .       A       T       30.80        1
1       317     .       T       A       31.40        1
```

I think sed is a little easier than awk for this problem.

[Overview of Regular Expression Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)

Later . . .

I see from your comments to other answers that you want to replace *each* occurrence of `x:y:z` with `x`. In that case, I'd use this awk program.

```
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN {
  FS = "\t";
}
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if (match($i, /:.*/)) {
        $i = substr($i, 1, RSTART - 1);
    }
    printf("%s\t", $i);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

$ awk -f test.awk test.dat
1       313     .       T       C       30.11   1       .       .       .
1       316     .       A       T       30.80   1       .       0       .
1       317     .       T       A       31.40   1       .       0       .
```

Comment: Dear Catcall, Thanks a lot. I am till trying to understand your script.

Comment: @jianfeng.mao: It just replaces a colon followed by zero or more characters with nothing.